How do I generate MS-Teams Media traffic to 13.107.64.0/18 port 3478 from linux host
I have a lab setup and wanted to trace the routing path it takes to reach MS-Teams (UDP traffic) - MS-Teams Media falling under IP range 13.107.64.0/18 52.112.0.0/14 52.120.0.0/14 and port 3478, 3479, 3480, 3481.
I have a linux host connected and help needed to simulate MS-Teams (UDP) traffic from the host

Simplest way would be installing Teams.

Welcome to the site. Please indicate what approach you have already considered, and where you faced difficulties. That way you can avoid getting answers you already know won't work.

If you need to trace the path, then you need to use traceroute -p <port> <address>, however, you may not find all the hops.
